# How to read a pdf from a url without downloading it?

Tags: java, swing, url, pdf

I am trying to read a pdf from a url without downloading and then i am trying to flatten it .

This is the code :

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import com.lowagie.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper;

public class FormFillAndMakeItFlattenPDF {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf");
         PdfStamper stamp2 = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Flattened.pdf"));
         AcroFields form2 = stamp2.getAcroFields();
         stamp2.setFormFlattening(true);
         stamp2.close();
      }
      catch (Exception de) {
         de.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

However, this is throwing an error/exception . This is the stacktrace :

```
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:352)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:214)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:530)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:480)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:406)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:541)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:245)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:318)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:335)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:832)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:773)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:698)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1021)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1009)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at FormFillAndMakeItFlattenPDF.main(FormFillAndMakeItFlattenPDF.java:18)
```

Can anybody tell me , what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: FYI, i am connected to internet .

Comment: Does the link http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf work when you try opening it from a browser?

Comment: yes, it does. try it out, yourself

Comment: is there proxy in the system? you might need to configure it

Comment: ahh, lemme look at that Nikolay. Yes that might be the problem .

Comment: I was combating with that connection timeout problem for a long time before and proxy was the reason in my case.

Comment: Okay, thanks, i will check that right now .

Comment: Yeah Nikolay, there's a proxy but how do i add your config settings to my project, it has no web.xml .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem happens because of proxy, call this at application startup.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", Config.PROXY_HOST);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", Config.PROXY_PORT);
```

where you change Config.X to your system values.

Note: for https you need to add similar lines with https.proxyHost and https.proxyPort

Comment: Nikolay, where do i add this piece of code, as this is a java project created in eclipse and i do not have any web.xml or cmd.xml configuration files for this ...

Comment: There is a proxy for the system, so i think i might need to know what you are suggesting .

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, its working now, i added the proxy inside the main method and voila, it started working. Thanks again .

Answer (score 1):

Your exact code works for me. I am using iText-4.2.0 (*) on Windows with Java 7.

Here is the code I ran, the test is green and "Flattened.pdf" is created correctly:

```
public class PdfTest {
    @Test
    public void testFlatten() throws Exception {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf");
        PdfStamper stamp2 = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\david\\Flattened.pdf"));
        AcroFields form2 = stamp2.getAcroFields();
        stamp2.setFormFlattening(true);
        stamp2.close();
    }
}
```

(*) https://github.com/ymasory/iText-4.2.0

Comment: Huhh.. it is more clever than I suspected.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight As your problem actually seems to be a network related problem, you might want to reduce your code to implementing a simple retrieval of the PDF from that URL and ask a question on SO more catching the eyes of Java network experts...

Comment: David, that i did, Once downloaded the pdf form and fed it to the code from the local. That worked handsomely. The problem is reading and trying to do the same from the url is not working. Anyways, i will tinker a little here to find out if there is some proxy for the sys set up. Thanks for your help, it's appreciated .